# Why am I getting a -3 on an AutoHotKey DllCall?

Tags: autohotkey, dll, terminal-emulator

I am attempting to use IBM's EHLLAPI to interface with their Personal Communicator terminal emulator. I point it to the location of the API, and specify the api name, as such:

```
hllapi(ByRef functionCode, ByRef data, ByRef length, ByRef returnCode)
{
  dllfunction := "C:\EHLAPI32.dll\HLLAPI"
  datatype := "Int *"
  rvalue := DllCall(dllfunction
                  , datatype, functionCode
                  , "Str"   , data
                  , datatype, length
                  , datatype, returnCode)
  If ErrorLevel
    MsgBox hllapi() returned %ErrorLevel%
  Return rvalue
}
```

However, it just returns -3, indicating:

> -3: The specified DllFile could not be accessed. If no explicit path was specified for DllFile, the file must exist in the system's PATH or
>   A_WorkingDir. This error might also occur if the user lacks permission
>   to access the file.

I have checked the permissions, and there shouldn't be any issues there. I have also tried copying the dll to the root of my C:/ drive to avoid any access issues, and that did not fix it either. Why can't it find the file?

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered the problem. I am using 64 bit AutoHotkey, and the dll I am trying to use is 32-bit. Once I switched to 32-bit AutoHotkey, it was able to find the dll with no problems.